# Setting multiple cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to set multiple cookies in `document.cookie`, but unfortunately only one is getting added.

I know there are multiple examples present on the 'Net for setting up these kind of cookies,and I followed one of them. But still I'm unable to set that out.
I followed this [link](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-and-cookies/)  to set my cookie.

**My Code:**

```
   function setCookie(start_time,end_session_time,total_time,flag,count){
     var cookie_string = "start_time="+start_time;;

    if(end_session_time) {
        cookie_string +="; end_session_time="+end_session_time;
    }

    if(total_time){
        cookie_string +="; total_time="+total_time;
    }
    if(flag){
        cookie_string +="; flag="+flag;
    }
    if(count){
        cookie_string +="; count="+count;
    }

    document.cookie =cookie_string ;
    console.log(cookie_string);

    console.log("document.cookie ="+ document.cookie);
}
```

**The Output:**

```
cookie_string :: start_time=1369926508266; flag=1; count=1
document.cookie =start_time=1369926508266;
```

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Answer (score 43):

Adding a cookie is performed via `document.cookie = "name=value"`
to add multiple keys, you should perform multiple assigments

```
function setCookie(start_time, end_session_time, total_time, flag, count) {
    document.cookie = "start_time=" + start_time;

    if (end_session_time) {
        document.cookie = "end_session_time=" + end_session_time;
    }
    if (total_time) {
        document.cookie = "total_time=" + total_time;
    }
    if (flag) {
        document.cookie = "flag=" + flag;
    }
    if (count) {
        document.cookie = "count=" + count;
    }

    console.log("document.cookie = " + document.cookie);
}
```

Comment: I didn't think this would work - because it is counterintuitive - but it does! :-O

Comment: Is there a reason for 2 semicolons on line 2 or was that a mistake?

Comment: @Jaketr00 That must have been a mistake. I've edited it.

Comment: @Brad, Yup...exactly why I googled it and ended up here :).

Answer (score 30):

Cookies are key value pairs (with some optional additional info added on, like the expiry date). To set more than one, you just set `document.cookie` more than once. The `;` separator is used to specify the additional info, not to add more different cookies.

Comment: please do provide a code sample. I believe setting the document.cookie variable the second time over-writes the first value don't it ?

Comment: It's counter-intuitive, but setting `document.cookie` does not overwrite already set cookies, except the one cookie with the same name, if it exists. And the way to remove a cookie, is to set its expiry date to the past. I recommend experimenting in the developer tools of your browser!

Answer (score 3):

There you go a sample example to add, list and delete multiple cookies

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var n=1;
function addCookie(){
document.cookie=n+"="+n;n++;
}

function ListCookies(){
var result = document.cookie;
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML=result;
}

function removeCookies(){
//document.cookie="";
var result = document.cookie;
var cookieArray = result.split(";");
for(var i=0;i<cookieArray.length;i++){
   var keyValArr = cookieArray[i].split("=");
   document.cookie=keyValArr[0]+"=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
}
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<button onclick='addCookie()'>ADD COOKIE</button><br>
<button onclick='ListCookies()'>LIST COOKIES</button>
<button onclick='removeCookies()'>REMOVE COOKIES</button>
<h1>RESULT:</h1>
<p id="p"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible to remove particular cookie? rather remove all the cookies. Assume, I added three values one after another. And I want to remove the second cookie. Can you please help @mateen

Comment: yes it is possible, just before deleting cookie check if its the cookie to be deleted.
like *****************
    if(yourCondition){   document.cookie=keyValArr[0]+"=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
}

Comment: would you be so kind as to check this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693350/display-and-delete-multiple-cookies-in-javascript/51694048#comment90350150_51694048