# how to use document and Request.Cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have two variables which needs to be created as a cookie. Can I give them just as without giving any expiration date but just as a key value pair,

```
 document.cookie = "<%= this.CookieDFKey %> = id";
 alert (document.cookie);
 document.cookie = "<%= this.CookieDateCompleteEnd %> = lastRunDate"; 
 window.location = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/GUI/DRNEW.aspx") %>';
```

When I gave the alert statement to check what value  it is having it shows me

[image]

I need to have both the values id and lastRunDate avaiable in the called page. Can I be just using `Request.Cookie[the name of cookie where the value store]`?

Comment: Is this server-side script? If yes, send your cookie in headers instead, and make them http-only if you can. Doing JS assignment like you have done means the cookie value is in your response body.

Comment: @TimothéeGroleau By Headers do you mean the URL. I cannot make them to the http instead they will be using secure connection. Is there any other approach for doing this? I am new to JS or C# –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First cookies are key value pairs, you will get all `cookies` in `Request.Cookies`

If i'm not wrong in C#

```
 if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"] != null)
    {
        string userSettings;
        if (Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["Font"] != null)
        { userSettings = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["Font"]; }
    }
```

Read the below url to set multiple cookies in `document.cookie`

[Setting multiple cookies in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842226/setting-multiple-cookies-in-javascript)

Comment: Yes I am using the `Request.Cookies[ConstantsBLL.COOKIE_DATAFILE_KEY].ToString()` to get the cookie value but it still return null,

Comment: if(Request.Cookies["DataFileKey"]!=null)
{
   var value=Request.Cookies["DataFileKey"].Value;
}

Answer (score 1):

```
document.cookie = "id=<%= this.CookieDFKey %>";
```

document.cookie = "lastRunDate=<%= this.CookieDateCompleteEnd %> ";

To retrieve cookie use the following code

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```