# Display and delete multiple cookies in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I want to display the last three search values on the website using javascript cookies. I store last three values but when I display in view it displays everything together. I have two question.

1. I want to display the values separately inside the `href`. So the user can click and search again.

Actual output

```
<a href="abc.com?location=1=Dubai; 2=India; 3=SriLanka">1=Dubai; 2=India; 3=SriLanka <span class='rmvcookie'>x</span></a>
```

Expecting output

```
<a href='abc.com?location=Dubai'>Dubai</a><span class='rmvcookie'>x</span>
<a href='abc.com?location=India'>India</a><span class='rmvcookie'>x</span>
<a href='abc.com?location=SriLanka'>SriLanka</a><span class='rmvcookie'>x</span>
```

2. I created `removeCookies` function but it removes all the cookies at once. I want to remove the cookies individually.

This website does the same. [makemytrip.ae/holidays-india](http://www.makemytrip.ae/holidays-india) Search by any destination. It stores the values and you can remove it individually. 
I tried last two days and couldn't get the right code. Can anyone help me? Please.

JavaScript

```
var num = 1;

function addCookie() {
  var searchvalue = document.getElementsByClassName("cookiename")[0].value;
  document.cookie = num + "=" + searchvalue;

  if (num >= 3) { //Limit for last three search value
    num = 1;
  } else {
    num++;
  }

  var result = document.cookie;
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<a href='abc.com?location=" + result + "'>" + result + "</a> <span class='rmvcookie' onclick='removeCookies()'>x</span>";
}

function listCookies() {
  var result = document.cookie;
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<a href='abc.com?location=" + result + "'>" + result + "</a> <span class='rmvcookie' onclick='removeCookies()'>x</span>";
}

window.onload = function() {
  listCookies();
};

function removeCookies() {
  var res = document.cookie;
  var multiple = res.split(";");
  for (var i = 0; i < multiple.length; i++) {
    var key = multiple[i].split("=");
    document.cookie = key[0] + "=; expires=Thu, 28 May 2030 00:00:00 UTC";
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="searchTxt" class="cookiename" name="asd">
<button onclick='addCookie()'>ADD</button><br>
<button onclick='removeCookies()'>REMOVE</button>
<h1>Cookies List</h1>
<p id="list"></p>
```

View
[image]

Comment: Why do you expect the cookies to be in different links when you only create one?

Comment: @Luca I'm planning to add this in the homepage next to search input field. I display the results based on the `GET` method. So if they click the `Dubai` all `Dubai` packages will display. Are there any other ways to do?

Comment: This website does the same. http://www.makemytrip.ae/holidays-india
Give any destination and search. It stores the values and you can remove it individually.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a solution on codepen - https://codepen.io/darius9171/pen/JBBRaz

Stackoverflow does not allow you to work in snippets with cookies, but requires you to write code when you specify a link to codepen. So don't pay attention to the snippet :D

```js
//set cookies
const cookies = ['Dubai', 'India', 'SriLanka'];
cookies.forEach((name, i) => document.cookie = `${i+1}=${name};`);

//render
const list = document.querySelector('.list');
document.cookie.split('; ').forEach(cookie => {
  const pair = cookie.split('=');
  
  list.innerHTML += `<div class="cookie" data-name="${pair[0]}">${pair[1]} <span class='rmvcookie'>x</span></div>`
})

document.querySelectorAll('.rmvcookie').forEach(span => {
  span.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const parent = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
    document.cookie = `${parent.dataset.name}=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;`;
    parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
  })
})
```

```css
span {
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this code nothing display on the browser. I checked the inspect element. It shows `Uncaught TypeError` error at this line `list.innerHTML += '<div class="cookie" data-name="${pair[0]}">${pair[1]} <span class="rmvcookie">x</span></div>'`

Comment: you send not my code. I used template strings that use this symbol - `, but you have a string that starts and ends with a '

Comment: I tried your code still nothing shows. Same error. please check this image. https://ibb.co/epNXwK

Comment: The error is that the variable list is null. do you have an item with class list in the document?

Comment: I see, there is. Try to place the script at the end of the document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177444/discussion-between-acmsohail-and-pryahin-v).